# How to assign value of textbox to another textbox in html?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to assign value of text box in another text box's value present in the immediate next line. How to do that using html and javascript?.

Eg:

> input type = "text" name = "test" value = "pass"> 
>       input type = "hidden" name = "hiddentest" value = "(here i have to get the value of previous textbox)"/>

Please help me..

Answer (score 7):

Assuming the two textboxes have IDs of "textbox1" and "textbox2", respectively:

```
var tb1 = document.getElementById('textbox1');
var tb2 = document.getElementById('textbox2');

tb1.value=tb2.value;
```

Answer (score 4):

First, put a function into your page that will handle it:

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">
function setHiddenValue()
{
  document.getElementById('txtHidden').value = document.getElementById('txtVisible').value;
}
</script>
```

Next, hookup the event on the visible textbox to call the function whenever the text changes:

```
<input type="text" onChange="javascript:setHiddenValue();"></input>
```

Comment: I am not gonna change anything. During the page load itself, it has assign the value to hiddeb dield. How to do that??

Comment: To do it during the page load, just add the following attribute to your body tag: onLoad="javascript:setHiddenValue();"

Comment: Get rid of the "javascript:" sillyness. In context it just labels a loop that isn't there. It *doesn't* say "this is JS" for that you use http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.2.2.1

Answer (score 1):

```
 document.getElementById('hiddentest').value = document.getElementById('test').value ;
```